# Which code/variable to look for to reset hearthfire Northwing extentions

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that console command:  sqv byohhousepale
                              sqv byohhousefalkreath
                              sqv byohhousehjaalmarch

Will give me a ton of enable/disable stats for the individual houses, My problem is I don't know which is exactly the north wing alchemy lab I created and would like to scrap for a storage room. Any tips are very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You could always save and try each one, reloading until you find the one you want. It'd take a while but then you'd have a definitive list.

Comment: thank you @Xantec I may be forced to try the trial and error method, I have no idea how to contact kotezot.

Answer (score -1):

From poking around in CK I have found there to be eleven rooms

1. Small House/Entryway
2. Main Hall/Back room
3. Bedroom
4. Garden
5. Enchanter Tower
6. Storage Room
7. Trophy Room
8. Alchemy Tower
9. Armory
10. Kitchen
11. Library

Please note that I could be wrong, the way things are stacked together is very confusing.
So, this amounts to my best guess.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but how does this answer the question?